# echo issue with WP function

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I am new WP user and please forgive me for any mistakes when explaining my issue.

I am having an issue with "echo". Here is the situation.

```
<?php echo '<p><img src="' . bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/img-1.jpg" /></p>' ?>
```

When I am trying the above code, the output is totally different. The url is displaying outside the `<p>` tag.

Like this

```
http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/themes/ThemeName<p><img src="/images/img-1.jpg" /></p>
```

But simple use like this - is working great. Why the above is not working?

```
<figure><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img-1.jpg" /></figure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`get_bloginfo`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) to return a string which you can concatenate, [`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) echo's automatically (in this case, while the echo string is being constructed, thus being echoed before the rest of the string).

```
<?php echo '<p><img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/img-1.jpg" /></p>' ?>
```

Alternately, you could do this:

```
<p><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img-1.jpg" /></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alexander for helping me. It was like a magic. Thanks again for the explanation. This will help me a lot.